# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^{2}}}{n^{3}}z^{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to apply the ratio test on this power series? I am very confused. Please can anyone explain it to me? My textbook's answer is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^{2}}}{n^{3}}$, then
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{n^{\frac{3}{n}}}=e$$

Therefore the radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{e}$ by the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem.

Answer (score 1):

As carmichael561 showed, the root test is a lot easier here. Also, your textbook answer is wrong.

Since you asked, here's how you can do it using the ratio test: let $a_n = \dfrac{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n^2}}{n^3}$. Then

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2} \left( \frac{n+2}{n+1} \right)^{n^2} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{2n+1} \frac{n^3}{(n+1)^3} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left( \frac{n^2 + 2n}{n^2 + 2n + 1} \right)^{n^2} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \right)^{2(n+1)} \frac{n^3}{(n+1)^3} \cdot \frac{n+1}{n+2}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^2 + 2n + 1}\right)^{n^2} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{2(n+1)}\frac{n^3}{(n+1)^3} \cdot \frac{n+1}{n+2}
\end{align}$$

Using the fact that $\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{a}{t} \right)^t = e^a$, the first term is $e^{-1}$, the second is $e^2$, and the last two are $1$. Hence the limit is $e$.

Comment: sir I got it but where z^{n} has gone?

Comment: @T.Noor The radius of convergence is determined by the coefficients (the terms multiplying the $z^n$

Comment: ok sir..can you please also explain how the factor \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{2n+1} comes?

Comment: $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1$, so I broke up that term into an exponent with $n^2$ and an exponent with $2n+1$.

Comment: Great!!! an average student's thinking is limited

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, the root test is the easiest. We can work the ratio test in a slightly different manner (compared to Soke's answer).

Consider $$u_n=\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^{2}}}{n^{3}}$$ and take logarithms $$\log(u_n)=n^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-3 \log(n)$$ $$\log\left(\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right)=\log(u_{n+1})-\log(u_n)$$ $$\log\left(\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right)=(n+1)^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)-3 \log(n+1)-n^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+3 \log(n)$$ $$\log\left(\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right)=n^2\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)-n^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-3\log\left(1+\frac 1n\right)$$ Now, for large values of $n$, use Taylor expansion for the logarithms. Replace in the last expression and you should arrive to something like $$\log\left(\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right)=1-\frac{3}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Now, using $x=e^{\log(x)}$ and Taylor again, you would find $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=e-\frac{3 e}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ from which you can conclude.

Comment: thanks a lot sir..its very easy to understand..thanks

Comment: @T.Noor. You are very welcome.

Comment: Using log is really natural here since the limit is $e$-- nicely done. +1

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it:

In
$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^{2}}}{n^{3}}z^{n}
$,
the
$n^3$
doesn't matter
(except, possibly,
at the edge).

Also,
$(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^{2}}
=((1+\frac{1}{n})^{n})^n
\approx e^n
$.

So the terms are about
$e^nz^n
=(ez)^n
$,
and the sum of these
converges for
$|ez| < 1$
or
$|z| < \dfrac1{e}$.

To see what happens
when
$|z| = \dfrac1{e}$,
the terms are about
$\dfrac1{n^3}$,
and the sum of these
converges.
Note that,
since
$(1+\frac1{n})^n
< e$,
$(1+\frac1{n})^{n^2}
< e^n
$,
which justifies these estimates.

Comment: thanks sir..my book says do it using ratio test..thank you so much sir

Comment: thanks for your help..now I got it